# How do i display out the arrays after Json.stringy and Json.parse

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

i have quite the trouble trying to get the notification that pop out at my mobile application to another page and store it as a history record.. but after searching around and trying many ways, i still cant seem to get anything out..

So here is the part of the code from **index.js** - Where one of the function is to display the notification from OneSignal

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // Enable to debug issues.
    // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

    var notificationOpenedCallback = function (jsonData) {
        console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    var notificationReceivedCallback = function (jsonData) {
        $("#message").html(jsonData.payload.body);  //display message received from onesignal
    };

    window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit("c651651-654e-987d-5f4a-65a4s65ddasd")
        .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
        .handleNotificationReceived(notificationReceivedCallback)
        .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
        .endInit();

}, false);
```

And this is what i had tried below the index.js code -

```
localStorage.setItem("notif", JSON.stringify(notificationReceivedCallback));
```

Here is another page that i had created to test if it can get the item @ notif.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <script src="www/scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script src="www/scripts/notif.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here.</div>
    <div id="printhere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

notif.js

```
var notification = localStorage.getItem("notif");
$("#printhere").html("notification: ", JSON.parse(notification));
```

So TLDR, my oneSignal notification that will pop out in index.html is kinda bad as it can only display one and if there is another notification popping out, it will replace the current one.
so i wanted the notification that pop out at index to be stored into notif.html/js in a table list format.. to serve as a record or history

So please help me out and maybe correct me :)

much thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to append the notification to #printhere rather than replacing what’s already there, so:

```
$("#printhere").html("notification: ", JSON.parse(notification));
```

becomes something like:

```
$("#printhere").append($("<p />").html("notification: " + JSON.parse(notification)));
```

Comment: but the problem is i tried but it wont display anything out with this code : "notification: ", JSON.parse(notification)) .. did i miss out anything?

Comment: I missed the syntax error in .html, the comma should be a plus.